# File `enum.sty' not found

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I am new to latex and was wondering how the error shown below can be fixed in Ubuntu:

File `enum.sty' not found.

Comment: Are you sure, you want to have `enum`, not `enumitem`?

Comment: This is the message that I get on 'build log' page of Gummi.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Of course, it was not found since there is no `enum` package, as far as I know.

Comment: Here is the latex template that I intend to use. It is actually for Elsevier journals. http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle

Comment: Do you load a package `enum` in your document?

Comment: Neither `elsarticle-template-num.tex` nor `elsarticle-template-harv.tex` try to load a package `enum`.

Comment: This is the template latex file. Anyway, yes. It has a statement like:  \usepackage{enum}

Comment: elsdoc.tex does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could compile `elsdoc.tex`, found in [this directory](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc), with a `enum.sty` by David Carlisle, found [here](https://code.oregonstate.edu/svn/vlsi/examples/latexPrimerExamples/enum.sty).

Download the file and put it into the current directory along side `elsdoc.tex` with its other needed files (images and packages).

But anyway, usually there is no need to compile the documentation source file,
because the [PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf) is already present.

Comment: Link to `enum.sty` file is broken.

Answer (score 2):

The `enum` package by David Carlisle was renamed `enumerate`. Simply change

```
\usepackage{enum}
```

to

```
\usepackage{enumerate}
```

The `elsdoc.tex` file provided by Elsevier [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/author-schemas/latex-instructions) has exactly this problem and this solution allows it to be compiled as per the README. Also note that elsdoc tries to include several example figures which are not provided (namely `els1.pdf`, `els2.pdf`, `jfigs.pdf`, and `els-3pd.pdf`); you will need to remove these references before it will compile.

## Buy why compile elsdoc.tex?

As mentioned by others, there really isn't a need to compile this file. If you're like me, you maybe thought that the documentation file would serve as a good template or example that shows how to properly utilize `elsarticle.cls` which you could then use to begin writing your paper. But as it turns out, **elsdoc does not use elsarticle.cls** so it really is pointless.

Instead, in the [zip file](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle) provided by Elsevier there are two template files you should use to begin writing your paper that are already setup with `elsarticle.cls` named `elsarticle-template-num.tex` and `elsarticle-template-harv.tex` (one does citation/bibliography in numbered style, the other in harvard style).

Therefore, you probably don't need to fix the `enum` problem if following Elsevier LaTeX instructions.